Eigenfunctions of the Laplace–Beltrami operator on the coadjoint orbit of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$
$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$For $\mathfrak{su}(2,\mathbb{C})$, the generic coadjoint orbit is $\mathbb{S}^2$, and the Laplace–Beltrami operator on it is given by
$$
\Delta \equiv \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left( \sin\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \right) + \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\varphi^2},
$$
which coincides with the differential form of the quadratic Casimir element of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. Its eigenfunctions are the spherical harmonics $Y_\ell^m(\theta, \varphi): \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$, for $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $|m| \leq \ell$.
Given this context:

For $\mathfrak{su}(n, \mathbb{C})$, is the Laplace–Beltrami operator on the generic coadjoint orbit the same as the differential form of the quadratic Casimir operator for a general $n$?

What is the explicit form of the Laplace–Beltrami operator, and specifically, what are its eigenfunctions (analogous to the spherical harmonics in the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ case), on the generic coadjoint orbit of $\mathfrak{su}(n, \mathbb{C})$ for general $n$?


My attempt:
The generic coadjoint orbit of $\mathfrak{su}(n,\mathbb{C})$, denoted $\mathcal{O}_{\SU(n)}$, is a fiber bundle over the base $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ with fiber $\mathcal{O}_{\SU(n-1)}$ (see arXiv:0801.2913). This is a Kähler manifold, and hence it admits a Riemannian structure. By evaluating the Kähler potential as described in arXiv:0801.2913 and differentiating, one can obtain the Kähler metric, and consequently, the Riemannian metric. Substituting this metric into the general expression for the Laplace–Beltrami operator on an oriented Riemannian manifold:
$$
\Delta := \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i \left( \sqrt{|g|} g^{ij} \partial_j \right),
$$
where $|g|$ is the absolute value of the determinant of the Riemannian metric, one can, in principle, compute the Laplace–Beltrami operator for $\mathcal{O}_{\SU(n)}$. However, performing this computation for general $n$ is extremely challenging and impractical.
In math-ph/9901002, the Laplace–Beltrami operator is defined as the quadratic Casimir operator itself. However, this approach seems ambiguous, as the coordinates used to construct the differential form of the Casimir operator (e.g., in their Eq. (33)) do not appear to correspond to the coadjoint orbit coordinates. Hence, I am unsure about the manifold on which this operator has been constructed.
Additionally, while the literature often discusses the eigenvalues of the Laplace–Beltrami operators and the quadratic Casimir operators, it rarely addresses its eigenfunctions. Here are some references I have reviewed but found unhelpful in addressing my questions:

MSE: Compute Casimir operator for $su(n)$ representations via the Weyl formula
book: Lie Algebras and Applications by Francesco Iachello
paper: Spin and flavor projection operators in the $SU(2N_f)$ spin-flavor group by Guzmán et al.
paper: Eigenvalues of the quadratic Casimir operator of $SU(n)$ in Young tableaux representation by Éva Szőke

How should I proceed to clarify these issues? Could you please provide some references for finding the Laplace–Beltrami operator and its eigenfunctions on the generic coadjoint orbit of $\mathfrak{su}(n,\mathbb{C})$?

For the generic coadjoint orbit as you require, i.e. the full flag manifold $\operatorname{SU}(n)/\text{(max torus)}$, the paper of Yamaguchi (1979) cited at this question has not only the eigenvalues, but also:

In Proposition 1, an explicit description of the Laplace-Beltrami operator, giving a positive answer to your first question.

In Theorem 2, the desired basis of eigenvectors after Cartan (1929).


